# High frequency sampling with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I need to sample signals up to about 200 kHz using the Arduino as a kind of oscilloscope. I have already seen that by itself it is unable to do it, since the sample frequency is about 9.6 kHz. But would it be possible to connect it with an external ADC?

Thanks.

Comment: If the signal is about 200kHz, the sample rate [must be greater than](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) 400kHz.

So, you actually can use some external ADC with parallel interface, but what do you do next with this data stream?

Comment: The idea was to process them in the Arduino to obtain a graph

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb for scopes is about 5X the frequency. 2X will give you some information but a lot will be missing. What is the voltage range of the input signals? How many bits of accuracy do you need. How about probes? Then there is memory.

You cannot access the internal memory of the Arduino so it will have to be external and dual ported. Dual ported indicates two different sources can access it. How are you going to refresh the memory if dynamic? Static would work but is more expensive.

I would highly recommend you purchase your scope unless this is a learning experience. You can get some very inexpensive scopes for under $100 or even a used one. I think these would work much better then anything you can build for for the same cost.

Many scopes have a interface to external devices can access them, this may be just what you need?

Comment: In the end it seems that I don't have to sample at such a high frequency. But, thanks for the information.